# Controllers split by areas

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-areas, asp.net-web-api-routing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I register a controller that has been created in an AREA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9485934/how-do-i-register-a-controller-that-has-been-created-in-an-area)

I have the question - is it possible to do the next?

I have three Areas:

```
_Default
SiteOne
SiteTwo
```

Inside each area i have a ApiController with the same name, but in different namespaces of course:

```
MvcAppliaction.Areas._Default.Controllers.ValuesController
MvcAppliaction.Areas.SiteOne.Controllers.ValuesController
MvcAppliaction.Areas.SiteTwo.Controllers.ValuesController
```

I also have a value of current (which i would like to use) Area in configuration.

I would like to map user to controller in the proper Area (which i can find in the configuration) if he enters in the browser:

```
/api/values
```

For example, if current Area in config file is SiteOne then this request should be mapped to MvcAppliaction.Areas.SiteOne.Controllers.ValuesController controller, but if i change current Area in config file to SiteTwo of _Default it should be mapped to correct controller.

PS. With MVC controller it's easy, you just have to set your route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    namespaces: new[] { "MvcApplication.Web.Areas." + SiteName + ".Controllers") }
);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My Suggestion would be to implement a custom DefaultControllerFactory.

You can see a very good example [here](http://omaralzabir.com/create_asp_net_mvc_controllers_under_namespace_and_specific_url/)

The default controller factory just lists all controllers by name on a list not allowing for this kind of functionality. The article above shows you how to create a new factory and take control over the controller creation allowing you to easily match routes to specific namespace's.

That would give the functionality you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks. I thought that there is another way. So, i will implement HTTP controllers factory.

Comment: No problem glad to be of help

Answer (score 12):

Try adding the following using statement and modifying the route registration in your AreaRegistration.cs file.

```
using System.Web.Http;
...
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
{
        context.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: this.AreaName,
            routeTemplate: this.AreaName + "/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
}
```

Comment: in this case, to access the controllers you have to write _/siteone/values_ or _/sitetwo/values_. But I want to write just _/api/values_ and get the access to controller from Area which I configured in config file. For example, if I specified SiteOne in config file and called the url _/api/values_ i will get the controller from SiteOne Area, and if I will change area in config file SiteTwo, then if I will call _/api/values/ i will get the SiteTwo controller.

Comment: I'd like to propose `name: this.AreaName + "_API"` or whatever naming convention suits you - so the route name will be `Admin_API` instead of just `Admin`. In addition I've used `routeTemplate: "api/" + this.AreaName + "/{controller}/{id}"` so I can access it with `/api/admin/users/123`. If you get 404 errors then you probably have a conflict with another normal MVC route

Answer (score 7):

[I've created a post about how to implement the HttpControllerFactory to support Areas](http://netmvc.blogspot.com/2012/03/aspnet-mvc-4-webapi-support-areas-in.html)

And now i can just specify area name in MapHttpRoute in the Global.asax file:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { area = configurationService.SiteName, id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```