# How do I route to an API controller inside an area in MVC4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MVC 4 WebAPI controllers splitted by Areas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9836030/mvc-4-webapi-controllers-splitted-by-areas)

This relates to this question and answer: [How to create ASP.Net MVC Web API Url?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9502480/8741)

I have a fresh, new MVC project with everything still as generated by the project template, except for one new Area called Admin. In this area I have ClientApiController and ClientController, and in view Client/Index I am trying a URL as described in the answer I link to, with the extra 'area' value.

```
@Url.RouteUrl("DefaultApi", new { httproute = "", area = "Admin", controller = "Client" })
```

However, the area part isn't working and I still get 'resource not found'. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I recommend the Route Debugger for debugging such issues: http://nuget.org/packages/routedebugger

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should have

```
@Url.RouteUrl("DefaultApi", new { httproute = "", area = "Admin", controller = "ClientApi" })
```

ClientApi

Comment: Bingo! So simple, so easy to miss. Thanks.