# How to call web api multiple GET methods through AJAX

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-ajax, asp.net-web-api

I have added two GET methods into webapi as follow:

```
    public IList<ProductDTO> GetAllProducts()
    {
        ProductManager pm = new ProductManager();

        return pm.RetrieveAllProducts();
        //return pm.RetrieveAllProducts();
    }

    public ProductDTO GetProduct(int i)
    {
        ProductManager pm = new ProductManager();

        return pm.RetrieveAllProducts().Where(c => c.Id == i).FirstOrDefault();
        //return pm.RetrieveAllProducts();
    }
```

Problem, when i only kept one get method `GetAllProducts()` then it works fine. but when i added `GetProduct(int i)` then giving me error as `Not found 404` error.

Please guide me how i could keep both the mthod and allow to access method having argument.

calling as follow:

```
           $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'api/values/GetProduct/1',   //giving error as NOT FOUND
            contentType: 'json',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                    //stringify
                    alert(key);
                    alert(value);
                    var jsonData = JSON.stringify(value);

                    //Parse JSON
                    var objData = $.parseJSON(jsonData);
                    var id = objData.Id;
                    var Cost = objData.Cost;
                    var ProductName = objData.ProductName;
                    var Description = objData.Description;
                    $('<tr><td>' + id + '</td><td>' + ProductName +
                    '</td><td>' + Cost + '</td></tr>').appendTo('#ProductDivWebApi');
                });
            },
            error: function (xhr) {
                alert(xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
```

i have added this WEBAPI into MVC 4 project.

its route shows as below:

```
   public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "ProductManagement", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
      }
```

Please guide

Comment: What is your route config? In your example you always get `api/values/GetProduct/1`, of course this gives a 404 if you remove this action.

Comment: I have not added additonal route, it just follows MVC application route.. updated question above with details of route.

Comment: What if you rename the parameter for `GetProduct()` from `i` to `id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The routes on the `ASP.NET WEB API` is different than `ASP.NET MVC`. You have the `GET` methods, so, just call the controller using the `GET` verb and the framework will solve it for you. I recommend you rename the methods to a verb, `Get`, `Post`, `Put`, `Delete`, etc.

In your case, call the method by `/api/{controller}/{id}`. In this case, `data` is a single object (because you have returned only a `ProductDTO`), so do not loop in it.

You have specified `json`, so jquery will be deserialized it in a object for you. For sample:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'api/values/1', 
    contentType: 'json',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        // data is a single object, do not loop in it.
        // you have specified json, so, it will be deserialized     

        var id = data.Id;
        var Cost = data.Cost;
        var ProductName = data.ProductName;
        var Description = data.Description;

        $('<tr><td>' + id + '</td><td>' + ProductName +
        '</td><td>' + Cost + '</td></tr>').appendTo('#ProductDivWebApi');
        });
    },
    error: function (xhr) {
        alert(xhr.responseText);
    }
});
```

I also recommend you to do some things like this on Web API:

```
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage GetProduct(int id)
{
   ProductManager pm = new ProductManager();

   var result = pm.RetrieveAllProducts().Where(c => c.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();

   return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, result);
}
```

On the `WebApiConfig.cs` file I recommend you configure the routes like this:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApiGet",
                                "api/{controller}",
                                new {action = "Get"},
                                new {httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint(HttpMethod.Get)});

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApiGetWithId",
                                "api/{controller}/{id}",
                                new {id = RouteParameter.Optional, action = "Get"},
                                new {id = @"\d+"});

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApiWithAction",
                                "api/{controller}/{action}");

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApiWithActionAndId",
                                "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                                new {id = RouteParameter.Optional},
                                new {id = @"\d+(_\d+)?"});
}
```

Comment: `api/values/1`,  `api/values/GetAllProducts`,  `api/values` these all three points to same methods `GetAllProducts`... but unable to call `public omega.learning.data.common.DTO.ProductDTO GetProduct(int i)`  please help me how to call..

Comment: Yup, it works... But why i am not able to call by Name. `api/values/GetProduct/1` and it works only when `api/values/1` Also, can we keep multiple get methods like `GetAllProducts()`, `GetAllProductTypes()`, `GetProductTypeById(int pId)` ???

Comment: The default name for the argument is `id`, so, if the argument's name is different, you have to pass like a query string, for sample: `/api/values/GetProductTypeById?pId=1`.

Comment: Now, when i add multiple methods - then giving me error as `Multiple actions were found that matches the request`... now, i have just additonally added- `GetAllProductTypes()` method..

Comment: Please let me know if you fouund this should be another question then, i will raise one new one and complete this by marking answer....

Comment: It is a conflict of actions. I think it is another question, but you could solve it creating a new routeMap, like [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14534167/multiple-actions-were-found-that-match-the-request-webapi)