# Get Request and APIs with/without parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have two APIs,

```
[HttpGet]
public bool WithoutParamBooleanResponse()
```

and

```
[HttpGet]
public string ComplexReferenceTypeParamStringResponse([FromUri]ComplexRefType VariableComplexRef)
```

However, this leads to having error

> multiple actions were found that match the request web api get.

If I were to add another dummy parameter for the second method, the whole thing works. Could someone explain why a parameterless method and a method with a complex parameter are seen similar by the API ?

Comment: Show us your route config please

Comment: config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }

Comment: They need different routes or you need to configure your routing so that it supports actions as well

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple actions were found that match the request: webapi](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14534167/multiple-actions-were-found-that-match-the-request-webapi)

Comment: What is your request url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why a parameterless method and a method with a complex parameter are
>   seen similar by the API ?

When a parameter is annotated with `FromUri` attribute and is a complex type, the value is constructed from the query params, therefore the route for both methods would be the same (since the query params are not taken into account).

Answer (score 1):

Try to create a new route like:

```
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute( 
     name: "ComplexRefType",
     routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{VariableComplexRef}", 
     defaults: new { VariableComplexRef = RouteParameter.Optional }
 );
```

and try to add attribute on your action

```
[Route("ComplexReferenceTypeParamStringResponse/{VariableComplexRef?}"]
```

Comment: I would note that solving this issue this way can get really tedious, and that instead it should be solved by adding actions to the route template or by using `[Route]` annotations on each controller method. Just my personal thought, though

Comment: Yeah, you are right. It's terrible to add new route for each method.

Comment: Also denote in your answer that `[HttpGet("{VariableComplexRef}")]` is ASP.NET Core syntax. In previous versions it is still `[HttpGet]` and `[Route("/yourRoute")]`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an action to your routing url.

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute( name: "DefaultApi", routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}", defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
```

When calling a route and only passing in a controller, the routing assumes there is only one action for each method(GET,POST..) and looks for it. This is why you are having an error with more than one GET. 
When you also pass an action, it is more specific to look for the correct action with this method