# Multiple actions were found that match the request: WebAPI 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I've read a few SO [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14534167) and none of them quite cover my scenario so I'm going to post here.

Given the following route config registration:

```cs
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    // Web API configuration and services

    // Web API routes
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

and these controller actions in a controller that inherits from ApiController:

```cs
public GetDocumentsResponse Post([FromBody]GetDocumentsRequest request)
{

}

public FinishDocumentsResponse Post([FromBody] FinishDocumentsRequest request)
{

}


public class GetDocumentsRequest
{
    public string CorrelationId { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ObjectId { get; set; }
    public string BusinessArea { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string SystemName { get; set; }
    public string SystemToken { get; set; }
    public Letter LetterDetails { get; set; }
    public List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> KeyValue { get; set; }
}

public class FinishDocumentsRequest
{
    public string CorrelationId { get; set; }
    public string[] Documents { get; set; }
}
```

I thought doing it this way would be enough disambiguation for the IHttpActionSelector to correctly choose the route, but unfortunately it is not.

So my questions is "Is there a way to make this code work correctly, and keep it in the same controller?"

Thank you,
Stephen

Comment: Were you intending to make the same URL call for both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [attribute routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2) for this.

Define the route as a string in the Route attribute ontop of the methods as this

```
[Route("api/controller/Post1")]
[HttpPost]
public GetDocumentsResponse Post([FromBody]GetDocumentsRequest request)
{

}
[Route("api/controller/Post2")]
[HttpPost]
public FinishDocumentsResponse Post([FromBody] FinishDocumentsRequest request)
{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The request routing pipeline isn't smart enough to determine if the body of the request matches the parameter type (aka overloading). (The compiler *is* smart enough, which is why this compiles and you have runtime issues.)

You have a couple of different options.

1. You can either add an `[Route(<ActionName>)]` attribute on both of your posts.
2. Make two controllers, one for `GetDocuments` and one for `FinishDocuments`
3. Make one `Post` method that is ambiguous. (I'd avoid this)

If you choose option 1, your API uri will have to be `.../api/MyController/MyActionName` rather than `.../api/MyController/`. It's also advisable to add `[HttpGet]` and `[HttpPost]` attributes on your methods.

Sample:

```
public class DocumentController : ApiController 
{
    // POST /api/Document/GetDocuments
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("GetDocuments")]
    public GetDocumentsResponse Post([FromBody]GetDocumentsRequest request) { ... }

    // POST /api/Document/FinishDocuments
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("FinishDocuments")]
    public FinishDocumentsResponse Post([FromBody] FinishDocumentsRequest request){ ...}
}
```

If you choose option 2, you have to maintain an additional code file.

```
public class GetDocumentsController : ApiController
{
    // POST /api/GetDocuments
    [HttpPost]
    public GetDocumentsResponse Post([FromBody]GetDocumentsRequest request) { ... }
}

public class FinishDocumentsController : ApiController 
{
    // POST /api/FinishDocuments/
    [HttpPost]
    public FinishDocumentsResponse Post([FromBody] FinishDocumentsRequest request){ ...}
}
```

If you choose option 3, <s>may God have mercy on your soul</s> you're going to have a bad time maintaining it.

Answer (score 0):

Add the Route attribute decoration to your web api functions and that will assit the selector to choose the route:

```
[Route("Post1")]
public GetDocumentsResponse Post([FromBody]GetDocumentsRequest request)
{

}

[Route("Post2")]
public FinishDocumentsResponse Post([FromBody] FinishDocumentsRequest request)
{

}
```

I also recommend adding the http method decoration such as  `[HttpPost]` or `[HttpGet]`