# List Data from DB using POST method in C# Web API EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, post, asp.net-web-api

I am working on a project and one of the requirements is to be able to list the value stories without using GET method.

I have my controller code here:

```
// POST api/ValueStories
[ResponseType(typeof(ValueStory))]
public async Task<ValueStory> PostValueStory([FromBody] string value)
{
    ValueStory valuestory = await db.ValueStories.FindAsync();

    var valueStoryName = (from vs in db.ValueStories
                          where vs.Id == valuestory.Id
                          select vs).ToList();

    List<ValueStory> vs1 = new List<ValueStory>();
    foreach (var v in valueStoryName)
    {
        vs1.Add(new ValueStory()
        {
            Id = v.Id,
            ValueStoryName = v.ValueStoryName,
            Organization = v.Organization,
            Industry = v.Industry,
            Location = v.Location,
            AnnualRevenue = v.AnnualRevenue,
            CreatedDate = v.CreatedDate,
            ModifiedDate = v.ModifiedDate,
            MutualActionPlan = v.MutualActionPlan,
            Currency = v.Currency,
            VSId = v.VSId
        });
    }
    return valuestory;

}
```

and this is the code in my model:

```
namespace WebServicesAPI.Models
{
    public class ValueStory
    {
        [Key]
        public int VSId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string ValueStoryName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Organization { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int Industry { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Location { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Currency { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public double AnnualRevenue { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }
        public string MutualActionPlan { get; set; }

        // Foreign Key
        public string Id { get; set; }
        // Navigation property
        public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }

     }

}
```

i tried to test it using Postman by just supplying the ID on the body but I am getting this error [link]https://ibb.co/gn5mZ5

I just started learning C# almost 2 months ago and I am still trying to get myself familiar with it.

Appreciate some help here.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14534167/multiple-actions-were-found-that-match-the-request-in-web-api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get this working by changing my controller code to:

```
// POST api/UserValueStories
[ResponseType(typeof(ValueStory))]
[Route("api/UserValueStories")]
[HttpPost]
public List<ValueStory> UserValueStories([FromBody] ValueStory valuestory)
//public void UserValueStories([FromBody] ValueStory Id)
{
    var valueStoryName = (from vs in db.ValueStories
                          where vs.Id == valuestory.Id
                          select vs).ToList();

    List<ValueStory> vs1 = new List<ValueStory>();
    foreach (var v in valueStoryName)
    {
        vs1.Add(new ValueStory()
        {
            Id = v.Id,
            ValueStoryName = v.ValueStoryName,
            Organization = v.Organization,
            Industry = v.Industry,
            Location = v.Location,
            AnnualRevenue = v.AnnualRevenue,
            CreatedDate = v.CreatedDate,
            ModifiedDate = v.ModifiedDate,
            MutualActionPlan = v.MutualActionPlan,
            Currency = v.Currency,
            VSId = v.VSId
        });
    }
    return vs1.ToList();

}
```