# How to Implement Method in Web API

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a web API controller:

```
   public List<mytable> Get(string filter1, string filter2){
    ...
   }.
```

I need to create another method named

```
List<drpSubject> GetSubject(){
...
}.
```

My WebApiConfig.cs like this

```
 public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {    
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            // routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            routeTemplate: "{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApiWithAction", "{controller}/{action}");
   }
```

But now I get error message "Multiple actions were found that match the request..." . It only works when there is one Get(). How to create web api that can take multiple actions? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple actions were found that match the request in Web Api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14534167/multiple-actions-were-found-that-match-the-request-in-web-api)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to configure routing.

You could change

`"{controller}/{id}",`

to

`"{controller}/{action}/{id}",`

More at [Routing by Action Name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api#routing-by-action-name).