# ApiController within an area

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-areas

I want to have `BlaController : ApiController`, with BlaController located in /Areas/XXX/ ( or namespace `MySolution.Areas.XXX.Controllers` )

The problem is that when I browse to `http://localhost:1935/XXX/Bla/SomeAction` I get 404.
Normal controllers (`: Controller`) do not throw 404.

*Note: SomeAction would be for example "public string SomeAction() { return "hi"; }", within BlaController*
*Note 2: Tried* `http://localhost:1935/api/Bla/SomeAction` *and didn't work either*

Comment: How have you registered your routes?

Comment: Err I haven't, since the normal controllers are registered automatically

Answer (score 1):

Based on this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9485934/how-do-i-register-a-controller-that-has-been-created-in-an-area), looks like you need to build your own `HttpControllerFactory` in order to support Areas with WebAPI.

The question references an article on how to do this: http://netmvc.blogspot.com/2012/03/aspnet-mvc-4-webapi-support-areas-in.html

Hope this helps.

**UPDATE:** 
Thanks to Bertrand who pointed to an updated article about WebApi support for Areas (which is still doesn't have by default).  The updated link is http://netmvc.blogspot.be/2012/06/aspnet-mvc-4-webapi-support-areas-in.html

Comment: There's no `HttpControllerFactory` in WebApi anymore. It can be done with a custom `HttpControllerSelector`. Andrew Malkov wrote a new version of that article you're linking to. http://netmvc.blogspot.be/2012/06/aspnet-mvc-4-webapi-support-areas-in.html